# How to fix the this artifact around the edges when baking? Or is this a normal thing?

Tags: texture-baking

I tried to bake normal from a high poly mesh to a low poly ones for video game and there seems to be some artifacts around the edges. Also the hole in the middle should appear more "rounded" but right now it looks like a hexagon. How can I fix them?
[image]

Comment: Not sure. Did you make sure to have smooth shading turned on on both meshes before you bake?

Comment: uv map every island with sharp edges, after that make a duplicate of your low poly and separate it, and then add a displace modifier with a very low height to use it as a cage...

Comment: No need for that, you can just set the extrusion level of the cage. We'd need to see a screenshot with the UV layout on top of the normal map. And of course, if you lower the vertex count, round is impossible.

Comment: Do these artifacts appear on the UV Seams?

Comment: I found it finally, it's because I forgot to disable autosmooth and change the image data to non color, I feel like an idiot now. Thank you all for trying to help.